# Hashmap vs Bundle in Android Efficiency and Performance Comparison

Tags: android, performance

I am trying to understand the performance impact of using a `HashMap` vs a `Bundle` in an Android program. I understand that a `Bundle` is a specialized Android component - does it therefore make it superior to a `HashMap` if one needed to simply store basic data types (`Integer`s, `String`s etc.) and not complex objects?

Comment: This might help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236751/android-what-is-the-difference-between-bundle-vs-java-util-collections-like-has

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: what is the difference between Bundle Vs java.util collections like HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236751/android-what-is-the-difference-between-bundle-vs-java-util-collections-like-has)

Answer (score 2):

`Bundle`s are actually built on top of `ArrayMap`s, which are memory-efficient implementations of `Map`s.  For smaller `ArrayMap`s, a search takes less computational time than computing the hash for a similarly populated `HashMap`.  But if you have more than a few hundred items in it, the `HashMap` will perform better.

Besides, `Bundle`s were not designed to be general-purpose data structures.

Answer (score 0):

**Bundle** allows to put String, integer, boolean, etc. into it but a HashMap allows only string, for others you have to convert them to/from objects.

One more difference is that with a Bundle, every object it contain is parcelable. This allows Bundles to be used as service parameters and to be attached to intents or fragments to passed into activities or fragments.

Comment: HashMaps don't only store strings. You can store any object into a HashMap as longs as you define the correct types when declaring the reference.