# How to deal with repeated code for many buttons in an efficient way

Tags: android, button

I have  about 20 buttons b1, b2,b3,...bn, with almost the same content, I don't want to repeat the same code, what I want  is: an efficient code in order not to repeat the same code, here's my code:

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Changes per button
            act1 = titl1;
            act2= tex1;
            act3=pic1;

            //Common code for all buttons
            Bundle b1 = new Bundle();
            Bundle b2 = new Bundle();
            Bundle b3 = new Bundle();
            b1.putString("somekey1", act1);
            b2.putString("somekey2", act2);
            b3.putString("somekey2", act3);
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Content1.class);
            i.putExtras(b1);
            i.putExtras(b2);
            i.putExtras(b3);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pushinhorizontal,
                    R.anim.pushouthorizontal);
        }
    });

    b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Changes per button
            act1 = titl2;
            act2= tex2;
            act3=pic2;

            //Common code for all buttons
            Bundle b1 = new Bundle();
            Bundle b2 = new Bundle();
            Bundle b3 = new Bundle();
            b1.putString("somekey1", act1);
            b2.putString("somekey2", act2);
            b3.putString("somekey2", act3);
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Content1.class);
            i.putExtras(b1);
            i.putExtras(b2);
            i.putExtras(b3);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pushinhorizontal,
                    R.anim.pushouthorizontal);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why do you create three `Bundle`s? You do know that a `Bundle` can hold multiple values, yes?

Comment: No, i thought it can hold only one value, please advise

Comment: Create one `Bundle` and add as many values as you like. That's why it's called "bundle" ;)

Comment: an Example please, I was loosing my time all those years and not knowing that :(

Comment: Seriously?? In the code you posted, simply remove declarations for `b2` and `b3` and replace them with `b1`. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) helps a lot.

Comment: Actually, you can not quite just change to using only b1 (although the reason may be an error in your code).  You use `somekey2` as the key for both `b2` and `b3`.  You would need to use two different keys (e.g. `somekey2` and `somekey3`). `putString()` docs:[BaseBundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BaseBundle.html). Some more insight can be found at [Android: what is the difference between Bundle Vs java.util collections like HashMap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236751/android-what-is-the-difference-between-bundle-vs-java-util-collections-like-has/6236801#6236801)

Comment: @Makyen, based on the poor quality of the the rest of the code, my assumption was that the duplicated `somekey2` was just a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a common listener

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity { //or Fragment
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { //or wherever you are currently setting your button listeners
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        ...
        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id./*button1 Id*/);
        ...
        Button bn = (Button) findViewById(R.id./*button2 Id*/);
        ...
        //set the common listener for all the buttons
        b1.setOnClickListener(mButtonListener);
        ...
        bn.setOnClickListener(mButtonListener);
        ...
    }
    ...
    //common listener
    private View.OnClickListener mButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnClick(View v) {
            //do common code here
            switch (v.getId) {
                case R.id./*buttonid*/ :
                    //do button specific stuff here
                ...
            }
        }  
    };
}
```

EDIT: (surrounded earlier code with the Activity class definition to give context)

Comment: I think this is the best method, however it is giving an error in begining, could you please give an example of a real 3 first lines:  @Override
  protected void onCreate(...) {

Comment: Oh, I assumed that was where you were creating the listeners in your code. It doesn't have to be there. I'll edit to clarify

Answer (score 2):

As I read the code is the same use `OOP` Concept make the code a function and call it

**Style 1**

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { 
            methodA(titl1, text1, pic1);

    }
});

b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { 
            methodA(titl2, text2, pic2);

    }
});

private void methodA(object act1, object act2, object act3)
{
        Bundle b1 = new Bundle();
        Bundle b2 = new Bundle();
        Bundle b3 = new Bundle();
        b1.putString("somekey1", act1);
        b2.putString("somekey2", act2);
        b3.putString("somekey2", act3);
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Content1.class);
        i.putExtras(b1);
        i.putExtras(b2);
        i.putExtras(b3);
        startActivity(i);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pushinhorizontal,
                R.anim.pushouthorizontal);
}
```

Now you need to Call `methodA()` when ever you want the same code to be repeated.

**Style 2**

```
private OnClickListener BtnSubmitListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

      act1 = titl2;
      act2= tex2;
      act3=pic2;

      Bundle b1 = new Bundle();
      Bundle b2 = new Bundle();
      Bundle b3 = new Bundle();
      b1.putString("somekey1", act1);
      b2.putString("somekey2", act2);
      b3.putString("somekey2", act3);
      Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Content1.class);
      i.putExtras(b1);
      i.putExtras(b2);
      i.putExtras(b3);
      startActivity(i);
      overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pushinhorizontal,
            R.anim.pushouthorizontal);
    }

};
```

Now link all your buttons to the Listener

```
b1.setOnClickListener(BtnSubmitListener);
b2.setOnClickListener(BtnSubmitListener);
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but act1, act2, and act3 are changing with each button, I mean for b1, act1=titl1, for b2 act1=titl2, and so on same thing for act2, and act3.

Comment: @MDMalik camel case btnSubmitListener.  Method 3 implements onClickListener  setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: @AndroDev, The edit by [Ma3x](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2422224/ma3x) makes style 1 use different values per button. Perhaps [MDMalik](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1248044/mdmalik) did not notice that those needed to change per button.  Your question could use a comment to make it a bit more clear that those are what are changing per button. As it is, every person that is interested has to compare the code in those two sections line by line to see what the differences are (this cost time and effort) instead of just being able to read a quick comment.