# Definition of Android Bundle

Tags: android, bundle

I am new to Android. Can you tell me what is a Bundle and how they are used in android?

Comment: I think You better google it then you'll get your answer

Comment: @Gouse Sometimes a focused question can deliver focused highlights and pointers better than a Google search. +1 to the OP.

Comment: Go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999991/what-is-a-bundle-in-an-android-application/30919826#30919826

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bundle generally use for passing data between various Activities. It depends on you what type of values you want to pass but bundle can hold all types of values and pass to the new activity.

You can use it like ...

```
Intent intent = new
Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("myKey",AnyValue);  
startActivity(intent);
```

Now you can get the passed values by...

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); 
String tmp = extras.getString("myKey");
```

you can also find more info on android-using-bundle-for-sharing-variables and Passing-Bundles-Around-Activities

Copy from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999991/bundle-in-an-android/5000058#5000058).

Answer (score 6):

Read this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html

It can be used to pass data between different `Activity`'s

Answer (score 3):

Android using Bundle for sharing variables. Bundle is used to pass data between Activities. You can create a bundle, pass it to Intent that starts the activity which then can be used from the destination activity.

[Here](http://miragemiko.wordpress.com/2010/03/20/android-using-bundle-for-sharing-variables/) is Good Sample Example.

Answer (score 3):

The Android developer reference overview states:

> A mapping from **String values** to various **Parcelable types**.

IOW, a Bundle is a set of key/value pairs, where it implements an interface called [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

Unlike a C++ map, which is also a container of key/value pairs but all values are of the same type, a Bundle can contain values of different types.