# Add item from activity(form) to listfragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

[add expense item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP4Gj.png)

[expense history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqEjD.png)

Input the form in image 1 and click the OK button, pass data from image 1 to image 2.
How to add item from one activity to expense history (another activity)?

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
i.putExtra("Value1", "This value one for ActivityTwo ");
i.putExtra("Value2", "This value two ActivityTwo");

Comment: why not use bundle
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999991/what-is-a-bundle-in-an-android-application

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

```
//in the Activity

eventsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // Lauching the Event details screen on selecting a single event
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String ID = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid))
                        .getText().toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                        EventDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra(pid, ID);
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Basically what you are doing is passing the id of the selected item in the listview to then the details in the fragment of that activity. Each time a different item is selected, a different details are shown. For further reference, take a look at [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) tutorial.

Comment: No, I meaning add item from activity to listFragment, not meaning pass data from listview to activity.