# Intent : To start an activity, unable to start the second activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

The application aims to write a message at the first activity, and after clicking on a button, this message appears in the second activity.
But After installing the application on smartphone, when i click on the button, a message appears saying " application is stopped". Help me please." i USED ECLIPSE for developping this application"

The first activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void login (View view) {


        EditText user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user);
        EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        Intent myintent= new Intent (getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);  //permet de basculer de cette interface à la 2éme aprés avoir éxécuter "startActivity(myintent)";

        Bundle b=new Bundle();
        b.putString("username", user.getText().toString());
        b.putString("password", password.getText().toString());
        myintent.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(myintent);
}
```

The second activity:

```
public class Main2Activity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        TextView mes=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mes);

        Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
        string user=(string) b.get("username");
        string pass=(string) b.get("password");
        mes.setText("user:"+user  +"password:"+pass);

}
```

Comment: show your logcat message

Comment: Make sure `Main2Activity` is defined in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Welcome To Stack Overflow. Read this for how to ask a good question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `i USED ECLIPSE for developping this application` **Irrelevant**.

Comment: When you see application has stopped, there is some exception for sure at back.
Try to debug the app and see logcat.
Logcat will help to resolve your problem.

Comment: have you register new activity in manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a simpler way to pass data as a String,without using bundle.

**MainActivity.java**

```
Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity .class);
i.putExtra("username",user.getText().toString());
i.putExtra("password",password.getText().toString());
startActivity(i);
```

and in **Main2Activity .java**

```
String name=getIntent().getExtras().getString("username");
txtView.setText(name);
String pass=getIntent().getExtras().getString("password");
txtView2.setText(pass);
```

Comment: thank you, it works now. but why dosen't wokr using Bundle? what is the advantage of bundle? thk you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999991/what-is-a-bundle-in-an-android-application

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
Intent myintent= new Intent (getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class)
```

to

```
Intent myintent= new Intent (this, Main2Activity.class)
```

And see if it solves the problem :)

Comment: This  answer doesn't make any difference !

Comment: thank you for answer, i tried it before, but il was the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

On Your **Second Activity(Main2Activity)** File:

The Line After 
`Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();`

you have written `(string)` instead of `(String)`.
So please change it...if u have written it mistakenly.

and @AugustoCarmo answer is also correct.

Try That Also.