# How to send color value to Bluetooth class?

Tags: android, bluetooth

How can I send a color value to my BlueTooth class?  For instance, in the code below, how could I send the hex value of a **text1** color attribute?  I'm using

1. Github.com/harrygoodwin/arduino-android-sensor
2. Github.com/trevorshannon/arduinocolor

Code:

```
private void updateTextAreas(int col) {
    int[] colBits = {Color.red(col),Color.green(col),Color.blue(col)};
    //set the text & color background
    text1.setBackgroundColor(col);

    if (isDarkColor(colBits)) {
        text1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); }
    else {
        text1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); }
 }
```

Comment: Please explain better.

Comment: i want to create one Bluetooth class and send color value from colorpicker activity  to bluetooth class

Comment: Are you asking how to do Bluetooth communication, or are you asking in what format to send it. If the latter, just send it as an integer.

Comment: yes,i want  to send HEX value to Bluetooth

Comment: private void updateTextAreas(int col) {
        int[] colBits = {Color.red(col),Color.green(col),Color.blue(col)};
        //set the text & color background
        text1.setBackgroundColor(col);
        if (isDarkColor(colBits)) {
            text1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        } else {
            text1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }

Comment: how to send text1 value to bluetooth communication

Comment: Hi Prakash M. M,  I think you are asking for passing values of color from one activity to another. If you want this, you can use bundle for this functionality. You can refer this link:                             http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999991/what-is-a-bundle-in-an-android-application

Comment: 1.Github.com/harrygoodwin/arduino-android-sensor

2.Github.com/trevorshannon/arduinocolor

Comment: please check the code and tell me solution for send color value i.e #fff00 to bluetooth

Comment: Cleaned up expression; edited clarifications into question.