# How can you pass the position of an item in your RecyclerView?

Tags: android

I'm trying to edit an item in my RecyclerView but I don't know how to pass the information (e.g. position in the list, values it holds) to the EditItem activity. Here is how I'm detecting the tap:

```
rvBucketItem = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvBucketItemList);
ItemList = BucketItem.initializeTaskList(1);
BucketItemAdapter adapterBucket = new BucketItemAdapter(this, ItemList);
rvBucketItem.setAdapter(adapterBucket);
rvBucketItem.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

rvBucketItem.setOnClickListener(new RecyclerView.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainBucketActivity.this, EditItem.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

I know that you can store items into the list using the `putExtra()` method but I don't know how I'd get the items themselves.

Comment: you should not use recyclerview.onClickListener method. you need to implement it in your adapter class. see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a "bundle" in an Android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999991/what-is-a-bundle-in-an-android-application)

Comment: @OmerKarakose I tried to but it confused me and gave me dozens of bugs I could not resolve. Like I can't even declare `private final OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new MyOnClickListener();` inside of my adapter class.

Comment: @Cheesebaron it's not the actual passing that's the problem. Like I said I could just use `putExtra()` but the problem is I need to "get" the information in order to pass it and I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please refer below code

```
rvBucketItem.addOnItemTouchListener(  
    new RecyclerItemClickListener(context, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        // TODO Handle item click with view and given position
      }
    })
);
```

Comment: It's not recognizing `RecyclerItemClickListener`

Comment: please refer more details http://alexzh.com/tutorials/recyclerview-click-listener/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a Bundle, this way you can transmit Data to the new activity.

> Bundles are generally used for passing data between various Android
>   activities. It depends on you what type of values you want to pass,
>   but bundles can hold all types of values and pass them to the new
>   activity.

Here is the link -> [What is a "bundle" in an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999991/what-is-a-bundle-in-an-android-application#5000058)

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. I have no problem passing information I just have a problem getting it to start with. Like how do I know what is the position of the item.