# Displaying multiple strings from getBooleanExtra

Tags: java, android

Since `getBooleanExtra` method has two values - `true` and `false`, how to write code using getBooleanExtra to display two different string values?

For example pressing `RadioButton1` should display string from getBooleanExtra `1` and pressing `RadioButton2` should display string `2`.

I wrote something like this but it isn't doing the job.

```
textViewDisplayResult.setText(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("KEY_ANSWER", false)?getString(R.string.1):getString(R.2));
```

**POST UPDATE**

so how to pass values to other `activity` using `Bundle` in below case?

```
 final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AnswerActivity.class);

    buttonCheckAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!allAnswersChecked())
                intent.putExtra("KEY_ALL_CHECKED", R.string.text_not_checked);

            else if (checkAnswers())
                intent.putExtra("KEY_ANSWER", R.string.Good_answer);

            else
                intent.putExtra("KEY_ANSWER", R.string.Wrong_answer);

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: You try compile it or made that up? Its not even compile `getString(R.2)`.  It's not have two arguments true and false..It has 2 arguments `name` and default boolean value, which is true/false. Make variable boolean of your "KEY_ANSWER" value and then in if clause set proper value.

Comment: Hi, I didn't  make it up. I just can not make it working. Can you please give me example of what you suggest me to do?

Comment: I've corrected my post. Thank you miljon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Since getBooleanExtra method has two arguments - `true` and `false`"... This is **wrong**. `getBooleanExtra()` has two arguments: one is Your key of the passed boolean value and other is the `default` value. So you can not pass two values using single `putBooleanExtra()`.

You can  use a `Bundle` to pass more than one values. See [this for mor info.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)

Comment: I've corrected my post. Thank you Kaushal. So if let's say I have `buttonCheckAnswer` with `if-else` statement, then the `Bundle` is the only way to display `Keys` in other `activity`?

Comment: I said you can use bundle to send more then one values. So if you want to send two boolean variables, then put them in bundle and send them.

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question for you Kaushal. Please have a look at my updated post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999991/what-is-a-bundle-in-an-android-application

Comment: Ok, but how to get `boolean` values into `Bundle` from both `"KEY_ANSWER"` which is `"Good answer"` and `"Wrong answer"`?