# Comunicate from activity 2 to activity 1 and update a List

Tags: java, android, list, android-intent, arraylist

My scenario is I have a `List<Object>` and I have the detail Activity where I can edit / delete, I'm wondering if is there any other way that I'm doing.

I'm passing from the `adapter` an `intent` where I pass the position of that object, and the Object itself, on Activity2 I do stuff and when I press delete or edit I send an `intent` with that action and the object and the position of the array, can you tell to me another way to do that efficient?

I thought a static List but I do not like static stuff to be honest...

**Without DB stuff**

Comment: This might help, use Android Bundle - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999991/what-is-a-bundle-in-an-android-application

Comment: @yashpandey that's the way I'm doing it, I'm passing the object itself with an intent

Comment: you can startActivityForResult ,send data and use `onActivityResult`  to get the new data back

Comment: For reactive UI, you can use Live data which automatically update your UI. You don't need to put effort like `intent` ,`startActivityForResult()` etc..

Comment: @Redman that's my way, yes

Comment: @farhana Don't get you

Comment: I edited the question I'm not looking for db stuff

Comment: @StuartDto just pass Bean Object of that position and do your stuff, and don't make it Static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good way will be to use some local database like [Realm](https://realm.io/products/realm-database) or [ROOM](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html).
Then you won't pass whole object via `Intent`.

In `Acitivity1` you load list of objects from local database. When users clicks on item, you pass `itemId` to `Activity2` via bundle.

Then in `Activity2` you can find item in local databse by id, then edit what you want, and save changes in database.

After returning to `Activity1` you can reload list from database.

**UPDATE**

If you don't want to play with local databases, then read about MVVM pattern + Data Binding.

In MVVM you have `ViewModel` which keeps your data, like `List<Object>`.

Thanks to `DataBinding` you can bind your list with adapter. And then all changes made on list will be instant visible in UI.

This is how it looks in Kotlin:

Binding list of objects with adapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("contractorItems")
fun setContractors(recyclerView: RecyclerView, items: List<Contractor>) {
    with(recyclerView.adapter as ContractorAdapter) {
        replaceData(items)
    }
}
```

Binding setContractors method with RecyclerView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/contractors_recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:contractorItems="@{viewmodel.contractors}"
    tools:listitem="@layout/contractor_signature_item" />
```

ViewModel:

```
class ContractorsViewModel: ViewModel() {

    val contractors = ObservableArrayList<Contractor>()

}
```

Comment: Can you put a small example RediOne1?

Comment: @StuartDTO I implement my application in Kotlin and it looks a bit different. Unfortunately, this can not be briefly presented. Look for information about ViewModel and DataBinding.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is using `onActivityResult`.

[Read documentations from here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

When you starting the second activity use `startActivityForResult` and when you finished the task, you can `set result` and the new data.

After that, when you finish the second activity, your new intent bundle will return to your `onActivityResult`.

When you received the data, you can handle your updates.

Also there is a good example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10407371/3669559

Comment: Yes, I'm doing this way, but I do not know if is there any other way efficient instead of passing full object and position of the list

Comment: @StuartDTO when you clicked the item, send position info with your object, and when you returned, update the position. Alternatively, you can search and find the data position by using uniqe value like "id".

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the same activity. If i understand you well you want to delete an item from list when it's clicked on.

`ListView.setOnItemClickListener{
     new adapterView.onItemClickListerner(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent ,View view,int position,Long id){ parent.getItemAtPostion(postion);//save this}
}`

Now you get the item, you can delete it and keep in the same activity.