# Passing Data through bundle using Intent

Tags: android-studio, android-intent, bundle, android-bundle

I want to pass data from Activity1 to Activity2 and then Data of Activity1 and Activity2 combined in Activity3.
how am i supposed to do it Android Studio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a "bundle" in an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999991/what-is-a-bundle-in-an-android-application)

Comment: Please spend some time researching your question before posting.  In life, you should generally not expect others to do work for you ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use intent extras to do this. Intent extras use a key/value pair system to store data. For example to put data you would say:

```
String name = "John Doe";
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("myData", name);
startActivity(i);
```

Then in Activity2, you would retrieve the intent, and then get your data back:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String name = intent.getStringExtra("myData");
```

Now inside of this variable name, you will find "John Doe"

Comment: how do i then then pass data to Activity3 of Activity1 and Activit2 Combined?

Comment: Theoretically, you could pass an array or custom object from Activity1 to Activity2, then append whatever data you want from Activity2 onto the array/object and then pass that onto Activity3. Maybe you should even look into something like Paper db or Shared preferences